# spark-mllib: Error "reassignment to val" in source code

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using IDEA SBT project to test spark-mllib code. Here is build.sbt:

```
name := "SparkTest"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.2.0"
)
```

After all the import and compile work has done, I found some errors in  lib source

> BoostingStrategy.scala(img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEt5D.png),

saying that

> "treeStrategy.maxDepth = 3(Line 80)" has error "reassignment to val"

Could anyone explain this? Is that the problem in sbt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did run [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-ensembles.html) from the spark website witch is pretty much identical. It does work even though Intellij shows the same errors. It looks like some bug in IDEA scala plugin. Your project should compile and work normally.

Comment: Thanks, bro! Glad to know it's not my fault:)